# Архитектура приложения на ASP.NET

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Задача состоит в разработке Web-приложения с помощью .NET.
На ум сразу приходит ASP.NET MVC. Но что следует использовать на фронте?
Используют ли еще Razor или это уже слишком устарело и следовало бы прикрутить еще React?

Answer (score 0):

Технологии выбираются под задачу. И у каждой из них свои плюсы и минусы.
Если вам не нужна сложная логика на фронте, вас устраивает отсутствие интерактивности, то Razor вам должен подойти.
Если же задача включает сложную логику, можно задуматься о spa.
На счет Vue и React тоже самое, выбираем по задачам и деньгам.
На Razor можно прикрутить Js-фреимворк, что скроет многие его недостатки.

Comment: В основном задачи сводятся к отображению данных в таблицах. Ну и CRUD операции соответственно. Просто вопрос еще в том как React на веб сервере IIS нормально будет?

Comment: React не пробовал, поэтому сказать не могу. Vue крутим, вроде неплохо работает.